# How to have manageable video size while recording using Android smartphones?

Tags: video-recording, digital-recording

I have Xiaomi smartphone with Android operating system in it. Whenever I record something using the front camera, even if just for a few seconds, the recorded video file size comes out to be very large as compared to the duration of the video. I say this because I have previously downloaded YouTube videos and movies of 1080p and Blu ray quality. Even for videos/movies of such high quality with long durations of a few hours take just 2-3 Gigabytes. However, in my phone, just a few minutes random video (made using 108 mega pixels front camera) can take nearly upto a Gigabyte. This makes making and storing videos difficult. I know many YouTubers make higher quality videos of longer duration and still those videos have very low file size compared to mine. Please suggest how do I record good quality videos and still have reduced file size.

Should I buy a new hardware or install any recording app to help myself?

Comment: Check the settings in your app - it must be set to the highest at the moment. If it doesn't let you change it, then you'll want to look at getting an app that can shrink your raw files down to a smaller size while keeping quality reasonable.